# mysqli_connect not working

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP script I have :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("12.345.67.89", "root", "password", "databasename");

if ($con) {
  echo 'connected';
} else {
  echo 'not connected';
}

etc....etc....
```

When I open 12.345.67.89/Register.php in my browser I get :

```
not connected
```

root, password and databasename are all correct. 12.345.67.89 is my IP address. Should I be putting something else in there? Is it the location of my actual mysql database I should be putting in there or just my digitalocean IP address?

I can access phpmyadmin by simply going to `12.345.67.89/phpmyadmin/` so I imagine the databasename should be working. Thanks for any help.

Comment: try this **$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "databasename");** added **"localhost"**

Comment: find more at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp - see your error by putting this code **mysqli_connect_error()**

Comment: if you want to use your public ip then you need to open mysql running port in your firewall. try lan ip or localhost as host name.

Comment: if you know about opening port in firewall setting just open port 3306 and see.

Comment: Ha, thanks guys. @Mit.agile I suppose you said it first so please put that in an answer and I'll gladly accept, I'm getting 'conected' now.

Comment: ok let me do that :)

Comment: @ChristopheHarris there you go at my answer at bottom :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "databasename");` added "**localhost**"

As mentioned above in comment

> if you want to use your public ip then you need to open mysql running port in your firewall. try lan ip or localhost as host name

So, please take a note on that.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, to enable the whole world access my database, is it ok to use "localhost" in my php script?

Comment: yes .. it should work now. let us know if you find any issue.